# Паттерн для пошагового выполнения алгоритма

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Нужно написать небольшое приложение, в котором должны последовательно выполняться шаги. Каждый шаг принимает какие-то специфичные ему данные и возвращает данные, которые становятся входными для следующего шага. Сделал примерную реализацию:
Интерфейс, который должен быть реализован шагом:

```
interface IStep
{
    Data Execute(Data data);
}
```

Интерфейс и реализация класса, обрабатывающего шаги:

```
interface IProcess
{
    void AddStep(IStep step);
    void Run();
}

class Process: IProcess
{
    private List<IStep> steps = new List<IStep>();

    public void AddStep(IStep step)
    {
        steps.Add(step);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var data = new Data();
        foreach(step in steps)
        {
            data = step.Execute(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Каждый шаг принимает на вход и выдаёт в конце данные типа Data, который имеет следующую реализацию:

```
public class Data: Dictionary<string, object> {}
```

В этом и заключается проблема: мне приходится использовать класс с константами ключей и в начале и конце каждого шага извлекать из коллекции по ключу определенные значения. Существует ли более элегантное решение такого подхода?

Comment: У вас параметры на входе и выходе методов разные или всегда одинаковые?

Comment: @tym32167 Разные, поэтому использую словарь и класс, хранящий константы ключей возможных значений. Если бы данные были одинаковые, то проблем бы не было)

Comment: А то, что в самом начале на входе и в самом конце на выходе тоже разное?

Comment: Кстати то, что вы пытаетесь реализовать сейчас в вашем коде эквивалентно комбинированию делегатов (см Delegate.Combine - пишу с телефона, потому могу ошибиться в написании)

Comment: Ну и как бы шаг тогда уж должен возвращать значение для передачи следующему шагу, а то как то нехорошо получается

Comment: @tym32167 да, на вход шагу передаётся коллекция Data, из которой в начале шага извлекаются значения по ключу, не обходимые этому шагу, затем выполняется сам шаг. В конце перед возвратом из шага коллекция может быть изменена. После передаётся следующему шагу

Comment: @tym32167 шаг возвращает значение

Comment: А, ну тогда точно смотрите комбинирование делегатов.

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Добавлю немного не по вопросу: для вашего интерфейса хорошо бы использовать [связный список](https://metanit.com/sharp/algoritm/2.1.php), когда у вас не просто IStep висит в воздухе - а из текущего шага знать какой шаг будет следующим.

Comment: @AK почему бы просто тогда не написать метод, который примет лямбду и вернет лябду, и этим методом построить что угодно :)

Comment: @tym32167 комбинирование делегатов конечно облегчает задачу проектирования, удаляя ненужные сущности, но передачу данных от шага к шагу это не решает) Придётся использовать или словарь с ключами-значениями или реализовывать для каждого шага свой тип входных данных, наследованный от общего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуем понять, что нам надо? Нам надо, имея функцию со входом А и выходом Б, добвить к ней шаг со входом Б и выходом С, чтобы в итоге получилась функция со входом А и выходом С. Попробую изобразить расширяющие методы для этого:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static Func<T, K> AddStep<T, TK, K>(this Func<T, TK> source, Func<TK, K> ret)
    {
        return (T inp) => ret(source(inp));
    }

    public static Action<T> AddStep<T, TK>(this Func<T, TK> source, Action<TK> ret)
    {
        return (T inp) => ret(source(inp));
    }
}
```

Выше я написал 2 метода расширения, первый для шага, что имеет результат, второй для шага без результата. Использовать можно так:

```
Func<int, int> step1 = i => i * 2 + 14;
var step2 = step1.AddStep(i => Tuple.Create(i, i + 20));

var ret = step2(6);
Console.WriteLine($"{ret.Item1} - {ret.Item2}");

// добавим шаг - действие (функция без возврата)
var step3 = step2.AddStep(t => Console.WriteLine($"{t.Item1} {t.Item2}"));
step3(10);
```

Вывод

```
26 - 46
34 54
```

Как видно, каждый новый шаг содержит в себе предыдущий + добавляет свою логику. Типизированность от шага к шагу сохраняется. Можно хоть 100 шагов посчитать, в конце это будет одна функция с первоначальным входом и конечным выходом.